# can't start rabbitmq-server after installation

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to use rabbitmq for a django tutorial but when I want to start the server I get this error:

```
~$ sudo rabbitmq-server 
Configuring logger redirection
14:49:57.041 [error] 

14:49:57.044 [error] BOOT FAILED
BOOT FAILED
14:49:57.044 [error] ===========
===========
14:49:57.044 [error] ERROR: could not bind to distribution port 25672, it is in use by another node: rabbit@wss
ERROR: could not bind to distribution port 25672, it is in use by another node: rabbit@wss
14:49:57.045 [error] 

14:49:58.046 [error] Supervisor rabbit_prelaunch_sup had child prelaunch started with rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase() at undefined exit with reason {dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","wss"} in context start_error
14:49:58.046 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.153.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","wss"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}} in application_master:init/4 line 138
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,\"rabbit\",\"wss\"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","wss"}}},{rabbit_prelau

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

I've searched for port to see that if it's in use or not and I used `lsof -i :25672` and I get nothing.

---

I don't know too much about these things so if you need anything please tell me.

Comment: we need captain in here

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

1. `sudo lsof -i :25672`
2. `sudo kill <PID>`
3. `sudo rabbitmq-server`

Where `<PID>` is the process ID that is occupying port 25672

Comment: Thanks! I was having this problem when running RabbitMQ and Celery on my Mac. I tried your suggestion and it worked nicely :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 11):

I have encountered this issue. I figured out that this issue is coming because the rabbitmq-server is already running on the machine.

I have used the following command

> `rabbitmqctl.bat status` to know the status of the rabbitmq-server. This helped me to know if the server is up or down.

If it is up, this could the reason you are getting the error that you have specified in your post.

You can issue the following command to make the server down

> rabbitmqctl.bat stop

Now you can try starting the rabbitmq-server by issuing the following command

> rabbitmq-server start

Note that I am using Windows. And I have executed these commands by pointing the command prompt  to `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.8.14\sbin` as my rabbitmq  installation directory is `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.8.14`.

Comment: Good, actually this was the issue for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**I have encountered this before. Here is what caused it and how I fixed it:**

This is one of those commands which requires the magic word ***sudo*** (i.e it needs a superuser privilege).
If you forget to add ***sudo*** to the command, it begins the process but later fails when it hits a superuser-only roadblock. This leaves you with an incomplete process. Now when you decide to add ***sudo***, it attempts the same process again but finds out that someone without the right privilege has made a mess or is still messing around.
Then the solution will be to cancel out whatever the first command has started and try again.

```
sudo lsof -i :25672
```

*This list out details about the port 25672*

You will see the PID (process ID) e.g 1301

Then stop the process on that port with:

```
sudo kill <PID>
```

for example, `sudo kill 1301`
***And make sure you are killing the right process if not you may get into trouble.***

Now, retry the command with ***sudo***:

```
sudo rabbitmq-server
```

ALSO,

In most cases, this error occurs because without deliberately stopping the *rabbitmq-server*, ***it always keeps running*** even after you restart you system.

Comment: Perfect answer, it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

another way to stop rabitmq server **windows+R** then type "**services.msc**" and then find for RabitMq.slelect and stop from left top corner.
Then re run your rabitmq server.

Answer (score 1):

-Hi guys, I am putting up an answer that can help Googlers to run multiple `rabbitmq-server` on the same machine. Trying to achieve the latter, I ran into a similar error reported in the first place and solved that by defining:

> export RABBITMQ_DIST_PORT=anything_other_than_25672

as stated in the documentation:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#epmd-inet-dist-port-range

Answer (score 1):

if you are using windows go to task manager and stop rabbitmq from running...
then reload the rabbitmq-server

Answer (score 0):

For `Linux` others answered but in `Windows` you should press `Ctrl+Alt+delete` and select `task management` and in that end proccess that depends on `erlang`.

Note that it requires `Administrator` previlage.
Now  enter this command to start `rabbitmq-server`:

> rabbitmq-server start

Every time you restart your computer you should do these steps.For prevent do them again you should stop rabbitmq service from `startup services`.

Answer (score 0):

went through same problem in windows, it is already running after installation as a service
so just enable the plugins from the rabbitmq commandline by entering the code as

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable management_plugin
```

than go to the localhost:15672 and good to go.

Comment: management_plugin
Error:
{:plugins_not_found, [:management_plugin]}

Answer (score 0):

This means that your port `25672` is already in use

try: -

- `sudo lsof -i :25672`
- `sudo kill <PID>`

and now start your rabbitmq server using

- `sudo rabbitmq-server`